# Ubuntu 12.04 live USB installation hangs

Tags: installation, live-usb, macbook

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook Air 1,1. I made a live USB stick using Penguintosh (the more common methods failed). Now, the regular amd64+mac installation hangs the moment I click on the installer, with an endlessly spinning cursor and nothing else, although the live desktop works fine before that. I tried suspending the computer to unfreeze the hard disk, as recommended in one place, but that doesn't solve the probblem

The alternate install gives me a grub prompt and nothing else. Typing "boot" at the command line gives the response "error: no loaded kernel".

Can anyone help with either the regular or the alternate install?

Answer (score 0):

is there al windows bootcamp then is be care full because the efi bootloader cant handel more then one bootcamps.... change than the bootloader there is a post in lifehacker how to this.

> > and/or try with this program it works for me
> >     http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ it only for windows
> >
> > > > or watch this 
> > > >         http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0Ae1mSICO8

Comment: Windows is not installed on this machine, although there is a backup install of OS X. I don't think bootcamp is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You marked your USB bootable . you should only extract ISO to USB without drive formatting .

Comment: On a Mac? And then what? You have to boot from the USB to install Ubuntu from it. Also, by "extract iso", do you mean dd it to the USB drive? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: i dont know make mac booting from device but if you maked your usb bootable you need only ecxract iso to usb folder